# Send email reminder for 'rolling tasks'

Tags: 2013, workflow, date-time, reminder, information-lifecycle-management

I have used this [question and Vedran's answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25178/best-method-for-sending-a-reminder-based-on-expiry-date) to have reminder emails being sent out based on a Date field.  It has worked really well and has meant I can avoid using the unreliable 'pause until' command in a custom SP Designer workflow (pause until often stalls).  I should explain that the email reminder for a task might only be sent once every two years.

The problem I have is with the way my Task List is configured.  **The Task has a DUE DATE, but the task is never done** > **the old Due Date is replaced with a new Due Date**.  This Information Management Policy (and the two timer jobs that 'power' it) are unable to cope with the **Due Date** field changing.  As far as Sharepoint is concerned it has already done it's duty and so will not send a new reminder email.

Here's how the Information Management Policy looks:

[image: Info Management Policy pic]

This kind of set-up happily sends the email and a reminder email 7 days later.  **However**, once the Due Date is changed, SP no longer picks it up.  SP thinks the job has already been done after it has sent a reminder once + recurrence reminders.

I could create another Date field and then add an extra Retention Stages in order to get a new reminder email to be sent from the new date.  However, some  tasks need a reminder every 3 months, I need a way to future-proof this and make it more user-friendly, intuitive and avoid having a dozen or more extra date fields.

I'm using SP 2013 on premises.  What are my options?  A custom Timer Job code?  Perhaps avoid using the Information Management Policy (and it's default Timer Jobs)?

OR - I get the user to change the way they use the task list.  Once the task is done, it's done.  Then make a new item and copy over relevant info from the old item to the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that what I wanted to achieve is too complex to use Vedran's Answer (see link in Question) - in a nutshell this approach uses the built-in Information Management Policy to send reminder emails.

I have set up reminder emails by going on the server and using a powershell script which is activated by using Windows Task Scheduler.  In turn, the powershell script runs a custom SP workflow.

Here's the process:

- Windows Task Scheduler is set to run daily (you need access to the server to configure this).
- Windows Task Scheduler runs a powershell script.
- The powershell script activates a custom SP workflow.
- The SP workflow verifies whether the Due Date = Today's date

  - if it does not, the workflow stops.
  - if the dates do match, the workflow will send out an email reminder to the 
    person assigned to that item.