# Email workflow at the end of the month with Count and Sum info from view Totals

Tags: designer-workflow, email, count

I have recently created a calendar view that counts each item created and sums total minutes for each session for each month.
**My issue is trying to report the Sum and Count functions as an email at the end of each month using a workflow.** As the manager of this department will be the one receiving these reports and doesn't work Saturdays when some of their staff does, if the end of month were to fall on a Saturday or Sunday the manager would not receive the correct data, hence the requirement for a snapshot in time.
I have a workflow already set on one of my calculated columns to copy out Total time on PC (in minutes, also calculated column) to Total Duration in minutes (number column), otherwise the sum doesn't work.
As you can see from the picture below, I have the Count and Sum functions working. I just need to email a report from that information, any help in this matter is highly appreciated.

[image: Bookings example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I don't wish to blow my own trumpet, this sounds an [Answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/235842/send-email-reminder-for-rolling-tasks) I posted for a similar issue.  If you have access to the server you can create a new task on Windows Task Scheduler, you'll need to find a powershell script that can trigger the workflow you have already created.

Workflows need a trigger to be initiated, since the day changing is not a trigger, we use the Task Scheduler > to activate a powershell > to activate the workflow > which triggers the email reminder message.

### Regarding the 'Sum' and 'Count' question

Have you tried using the 'export to excel' feature, it is in List Settings.  I have used this a lot for making reports; it grabs all your Sharepoint list data -> exports it to Excel.

If you save the initial exported data as a template i.e. `Excel Report for Bossman Template`, it saves as a linked file.  Then when you need to make next week's report you can reopen your template>file>save as `Report for Boss Week 2`.  The advantage of using this kind of linked file is that you can format your report to make it more presentable; add in a header and footer, page set-up etc.  You can even set up graphs which refresh when new data is pulled in from Sharepoint.

Then you can use Excel to do the Sum and Count for you.  I guess your boss doesn't mind which format the report is in, bosses often like Excel reports!

I hope this helps.  A bit of experimentation with linked files is well worth the time invested in tinkering with it, until you get the hang of it.

Comment: That's really helpful and I will probably need that, however how do I report on the sum= and count= fields?

Comment: hmm, I see what you mean - I'll update my answer

Comment: Thanks very much for your time, I will look into this!!!