# Workflow for prompt user to enter KPI absent value

Tags: workflow

I have a KPI list (custom list) that includes KPI values by months. Every KPI is assign to responsible users (defined in people/group column). I need to write a workflow (sharepoint 2010) to prompt these user to enter values unless data during that month by e-mail. Is there any example that i might be inspired from?

Comment: You can refer to this post <https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/gg508985(v=office.14)>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to coordinate something like this before, now this isn't what you've asked for, but I thought I would mention it.  You can use a view to filter on the people/group column (I'll call this column `Assigned To`).

If you make a new view and call it e.g. KPI Reporter; in this view in the filter section configure it like this:

[image: Assigned To equal to [Me]]

A user will see the KPI that they are responsible for reporting on.  For the project I was working on, I would send out a monthly email reminder asking users to update with their latest KPI numbers.  In the email I would include a link to the KPI Reporter view; the user clicks on it and sees their KPIs.

Regarding workflows, this is a bit more complex.  I see that you are a new user (welcome!), so I have no way of gauging your proficiency with Sharepoint, but you seem up for a challenge.  You might find [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/236003/workflow-to-send-reminder-email-based-on-reminder-date/236007#236007) is useful.

One other suggestion, you might like to experiment with an Out-Of-The-Box Task List - since these automatically send an email to notify of a task being assigned.  However, the problem is that it sends one email to the `Assigned To` and won't send another email unless the `Assigned To` changes - in your case, the `Assigned To` is not going to change (unless the person leaves the company or changes jobs within the company).  You'd have to customise it to make it work..

### Update

If you are able to log on to the server you can configure a new task on Windows Task Scheduler.  The task is the 'spark' which can be used to trigger a workflow, therefore you would not need to manually start a workflow.  Here is a link to a post I made on this previously, don't read the Question (as it might be confusing and does not apply for your case), but the [Answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/235842/send-email-reminder-for-rolling-tasks) is relevant.

Further reading - check out [this post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9640cb76-435c-4b62-8c8a-4dc7665676fa/what-is-the-best-approach-to-run-task-scheduler-with-regards-to-sharepoint-servers-vs-apps-server?forum=sharepointadmin), it contains links to two very relevant posts on Stack Exchange - it's all about timer jobs, though there's a lot of information here to read through.

Comment: thank for your answer. as you mentioned i am not a SharePoint developer so i am not familiar with workflow syntax. But i like to turn my manuel operational to automation.  I already set filter section which is very useful. One of my sharepoint developer friend suggest me to write code in console instead of workflow and convert to exe. Then set it into a job that searches for missing data in the custom list everyday and send notification mails. Currently it sounds like "manuel for life" for me :)

Comment: Well, this is a more complex suggestion, but you could try using a Windows Task Scheduler t o run a Powershell script.  This requires no manual trigger to run the workflow to check whether notifications need to be sent.  I've updated my answer.