# Send 30 days reminder

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, designer-workflow

I am trying to use SharePoint designer to send an email notification 30 days before Original Due date. also, if the status field is not equal to close, the system should send email every 14 days.

I have difficulties to get the second part which needs to keep sending email until the status is close. Can you please help?

[image]

Comment: So Harris, did you fix your issue?  Or did you find another way to make it work?  I'm waiting in suspense to know whether you got this working...the silence is killing me..

Answer (score 0):

For 2010 workflow, you will need to use a tricky way to do this without loop. Using two workflows like this [blog](http://sharepoint713.blogspot.com/2011/09/sharepoint-designer-workflow-to-send.html). Or you may need to set up a windows task which will initiate a workflow every 14 days, check the status and then send a Email

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you only a part-answer and another option.  Windows Task Scheduler can be used as your 'date trigger', the WTS task can be configured to kick off a powershell script.   The end product is that an email is sent out.

I had a [similar scenario here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/235842/send-email-reminder-for-rolling-tasks), please read the answer for an outline of this method.  It's been ages since I did this though, I've since changed jobs so no longer have the .ps script I used.  But you could try doing some research on this if it seems promising for your scenario.

### For reference

How to [create an automated task using Task Scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10) on Windows 10.

You'd still need to find a suitable powershell script though.