# Workflow to send Reminder Email based on Reminder Date

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, email, date, reminder

I am currently dealing with a doubt rather than a problem. I would appreciate it if you could help me out.

So i have a workflow in which i pause it until the reminder date and then send an email.

I wanted to know that whether this workflow will work to send email to all users whose reminder date is coming or how will this workflow work.

I am new to share Point so would love if you guys could help me out.

[image]

Comment: If a list is concerned , then the particular email will be triggered according to the date/item submitted.

Comment: yes a list is concerned. 
So the reminder date won't work automatically?
i want the users to get an automatic email on the reminder date.

Answer (score 1):

'Pause until' is unreliable and times out if the waiting period is long - this is what I have read, rather than experienced personally.

There are some good posts on this site already addressing this question & some answers that you might find useful - [link1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/145697/pause-until-date-workflows-unable-to-handle-changing-dates) and [link2](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/164270/is-it-a-hindrance-to-have-a-workflow-wait-for-a-long-period-of-time).

### **Possible alternative configuration**

*If it's a one-off task and the Reminder Date will not change, then this is a good solution*.

Depending on how your Reminder Date will be used, you might wish to use a reminder system that utilises the built-in **Information Management Policy** as described in [Vedran's answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25178/best-method-for-sending-a-reminder-based-on-expiry-date) to this question.  The IM Policy is triggered by two timer jobs, so you are reusing something that is OOTB in Sharepoint, albeit for a different purpose.

However, a word of caution, if the Reminder Date is likely to change, you may wish to find another option.  I have an [open question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/235842/send-email-reminder-for-rolling-tasks) on this issue (where the Reminder Date is changed OR when the reminder email has already been sent and the user wishes to enter a new Reminder Date in the future - SP won't send a second email reminder).  Though I'm starting to think custom coding would handle it instead of trying to reuse the OOTB IM Policy.

Comment: So let me give you a brief on Reminder Date. I have a workflow where in if the status changes to say for example "xyz", time stamp column captures today date as to when the change has been made and does reminder date contains one day added to the updated date which is time stamp.
so when ever status is updated to xyz reminder date is captured.
and after that the above workflow comes into picture.
now is it a feasible workflow?

Comment: 'Pause until' is unreliable and times out if the waiting period is long.  A workflow is triggered by item creation or modification - so if a user modifies the item, the workflow is triggered and can check through whatever conditions you wish to define.  Then it will decide whether or not to send the email

Comment: So i am going through some trouble now with the workflow. You were correct. So i build 2 stages in one workflow where it pauses till reminder date and then sends email in stage 2 but it gets suspended in stage 1 due to some error.
how do i resolve this any idea?

Comment: You could use the 'possible alternative configuration' I suggested (depending on the nature of the item - will the reminder date be changed?).  Or you use custom code, but I can't help with that.  Or you ask users to regularly check their tasks.

Comment: I will give it a try. Actually every user will have a different reminder date.

Comment: If you do try my alternative suggestion it will only send one reminder - so once a reminder email has been sent, SP will not send another email even if the Reminder Date changes.  SP thinks it has already done it, so will not send another.  So perhaps this will be unsuitable for your users.

Comment: So it will send the email for each user once right?
if that is possible then it sounds perfectly fine.
i have another issue regarding email.
here is a link to it
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/236104/email-being-sent-to-me-and-not-to-other-users?noredirect=1#comment252403_236104

Could you please give it a look.
Thank You for your help.

Comment: Yes - please note that the solution I've suggested runs off a Timer Job - please refer to this post [link](https://sharepointmaven.com/set-retention-deletion-policies-files-folders-sharepoint/) (scroll down and read the heading marked Timer Job).  re: your other question - just tell Robert whether or not you are using Sharepoint Online and he can help you

Comment: yo can use a workflow with the pause until... action. set up the workflow to run when an item is added or updated. when an item is updated, use some javascript code in the presage action to cancel any running workflow, that way, when the item gets saved, a new workflow will be started with the new date. I have the code somewhere if u need it.